# How to convert a large JMeter summary report to a chart

Tags: charts, jmeter

I have a set of large summary reports from JMeter test cases. The reports contain test results where I have a large number of threads in long-running loops. The summary reports provide me with all the statistics I need, but I would like to be able to convert these reports to graphs/charts. This would allow me to show whether the tests were scaling linearly and so on.

My reports are so large that it doesn't look possible to convert them to graphs within JMeter itself. Can anyone recommend a way of converting large summary reports into decent looking charts? I'm particularly interested in graphing the throughput and response times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gzip your files and upload them to [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org), you'll have several graphs for your test.

Also you may use [JMeterPluginsCMD](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD) tool to create graphs from command line, this brings you some automation with long-running result analysis.

Comment: Both of those look really useful thanks. Can you tell me if the 'Deliverd Load' chart on Loadosophia.org is actually my throughput?

Comment: Yes, it is your transaction throughput

Comment: Got some great graphs off the JMeterPluginsCMD plugin thanks!